# Does a "pyramid" structure help guide UX in lists?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, lists

The context here is presenting a short feature list on a website.  My searches have not yielded any specific research on what makes for a good structure for a list of features.  Intuitively, I have a feeling that guiding the UX by

- Centering the feature list items in their container
- Starting with the simplest, most easily understood feature
- Structuring the length of the subsequent items to create a "pyramid"

would help spark and hold the user's attention.  Here is what I mean

```
              Saves Money
        Works with or without gas
Pollution free, noise free, easy to control
```

I am curious to know if there is any evidence out there that this does indeed help.  That apart, are there any formal studies that look at the impact of list item content and layout on UX?  Hopefully, someone here will be able to comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You have two challenges: how users scan and read (presentation), and how you prioritize content for inducing readers to engage more with your message (content).

Centered and increasingly longer line lengths do not make for better legibility. The eye has to increasingly zip back and forth.

Length !== Increasingly Interesting Content. Screen reading is tiresome.

You actually have a potential solution embedded in your question: the bulleted list for [scannability](https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2015/06/scannability-principle-and-practice.php).

- Saves time
- My eyes don't have to dart back and forth to increasingly longer lines
- Works on small viewports: the list retains it's structure. Centered unmoored text can increasingly bunch up.

See this Nielsen Norman Group article on legibility:
**[Succinct Writing for the Web](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/be-succinct-writing-for-the-web/)**

> Simply chunking your text isn’t enough — you also need to support scanning by making it easy to quickly identify the main points of the chunks. You can do this by including:
> Headings and subheadings that clearly contrast with the rest of the text (bolder, larger, etc.)
> Highlighted keywords (bold, italic, etc.)
> Bulleted or numbered lists
> A short summary paragraph for longer sections of text, such as articles

From **[Presenting bulleted lists](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/presenting-bulleted-lists/)**

> Readers perceive the bullets as shortcuts to succinct, high-priority content. It’s not surprising that, in usability studies, we observe readers gravitate towards bulleted lists with fervor. Web readers want to digest content quickly.

#### There is a pyramid that is useful, but it doesn't have to do with visual presentation. It's about content.

For content, put the most important things first.

If you want to engage users, you might want to look at the **[Inverted Pyramid of Journalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid_(journalism))**

> The widest part at the top represents the most substantial, interesting, and important information that the writer means to convey, illustrating that this kind of material should head the article, while the tapering lower portion illustrates that other material should follow in order of diminishing importance.

[image]